# query optimization with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I want to optimze the follwing query, to not use subquery to get max value:

```
select c.ida2a2 from table1 m, table2 c 
where c.ida3a5 = m.ida2a2 
and (c.createstampa2 < (select max(cc.createstampa2) 
                        from table2 cc where cc.ida3a5 = c.ida3a5));
```

Any idea? Please let me know if you want to get more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a more efficient way to write the query:

```
select c.ida2a2
from table1 m join
     (select c.*, MAX(createstampa2) over (partition by ida3a5) as maxcs
      from table2 c 
     ) c
     on c.ida3a5 = m.ida2a2
where c.createstampa2 < maxcs
```

I'm pretty sure Oracle optimizes this correctly (filtering the rows before the join).  If you wanted to be clearer:

```
select c.ida2a2
from table1 m join
     (select c.*
      from (select c.*, MAX(createstampa2) over (partition by ida3a5) as maxcs
            from table2 c 
           ) c
      where c.createstamp2 < c.maxcs
     ) c
     on c.ida3a5 = m.ida2a2
```

Comment: @rs. . . . You are correct.  For some reason, I had the `where` condition using the `m` table in my mind rather than the `c` table.